# Randomly generated maze

Tags: python, maze

I am trying to create a randomly generated maze which fits very specific criteria:
I would like it in a 2D list, where walls are False and passages are True
there should only be one rout from point x to point y.
Here's what I have so far:

```
def generate(height,width):
    maze_lst=[]
    theight = height*2+1
    twidth = width*2+1
    maze_lst = gen_base(theight, twidth)
    maze_lst = entrance(theight, twidth, maze_lst)
    #maze_lst = route(theght, twidth, maze_lst)
    return maze_lst

def gen_base(height, width):
    maze_lst = []
    for i in range(height):
        maze_lst.append([])
        for j in range(width):
            if int(i/2) == i/2:
                maze_lst[i].append(False)
            elif int(j/2) == j/2:
                maze_lst[i].append(False)
            else:
                maze_lst[i].append(True)
    return maze_lst

def entrance(height, width, maze_lst):
    oside=0
    oblock=0
    for i in range(2):
        side = randint(1,4)
        if side == 1:
            block = randint(1,int(width/2))
            maze_lst[0][block*2-1] = True
        if side == 2:
            block = randint(1,int(height/2))
            maze_lst[block*2-1][width-1] = True
        if side == 3:
            block = randint(1,int(width/2))
            maze_lst[height-1][block*2-1] = True
        if side == 4:
            block = randint(1,int(height/2))
            maze_lst[block*2-1][0] = True

        if side==oside and block==oblock:
            maze_lst=generate(height,width)
        else:
            oside=side
            oblock=block
    return maze_lst

def route(height, width, maze_lst):
    ?
    return maze_lst
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please point out what is wrong with your code and what you wish to improve.

Answer (score 0):

There are [many different algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) to create mazes. Wikipedia has a [Python example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Python_code_example).